# Twilio Taskrouter: Play message before connecting to worker

Tags: ruby, twilio, worker, twilio-click-to-call

I am using Twilio Taskrouter to handle multiple calls coming from customers and assign them to workers.

Its working perfectly for me.. Thanks to Twilio..

The enhancement I want to add it here is:

Before assigning worker to my task which is in queue, I want to play some ring so that Customer will come to know that he is going to connect to our Staff.

Currently it just plays hold-music and in between get connected to our Staff by using workers.

Does twilio provides us any way to play some ring or some message like "we are connecting you to one of our staff" etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio employee here. How are you connecting the caller to the agent? Are you using the [dequeue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#dequeue-call) assignment instruction? If you'd like a more customized experience you can instead use the [dial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#initiating-call) assignment instruction. That allows you to customize the TwiML that gets executed. You would just need to make sure that your TwiML looks something like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Queue reservationSid="reservationSid"/>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes @cater-rabasa I am using dequeue assignment instruction. Thanks for the reply, I will try above solution and let you know soon :)

Comment: Previously I have following: 
`assignment_instruction = {instruction: 'dequeue',  post_work_activity_sid: "--",
from: TWILIO_NUMBER,
to: dynamic_mobile
}`..
This works fine..
Now changing it to..
`assignment_instruction = {
  instruction: 'call',
  from: TWILIO_NUMBER,
  url: api_v1_twilio_answer_donor_call_url,
  to: dynamic_mobile,
  accept: true
}` and this my action `def answer_donor_call
response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
r.Play "We are connecting you now.."
end
render_twiml response
end`
But this does not work, no call is done to dynamic_mobile number.. am I missing anything?

Comment: That looks good to me. Can you please send an email to help@twilio.com and we'll try to debug what's going wrong?

Comment: Yeah, just emailed all the details. Thanks :)